# class JComboBox takes type parameters

Tags: swing, scala, parameters, casting, jcombobox

I want to get value of instance of JComboBox in my listener:

```
object NoteListener extends ActionListener {
  def actionPerformed(e:ActionEvent):Unit = {
    println("Source: " + e.getSource.asInstanceOf[JComboBox].getValue)
  }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
[error] .../test.scala:30:  class JComboBox takes type parameters
[error] println("Source: " + e.getSource.asInstanceOf[JComboBox].getValue)
```

when I try to pass any parameter:

```
[error] .../test.scala:30: ']' expected but '(' found.
[error] println("Source: " + e.getSource.asInstanceOf[JComboBox(Array)].getValue)
```

Is it a bug, or my ignorance?

Comment: I don't know scala but perhaps it has something to do with a change to `JComboBox` (and other Swing classes) in Java 7, which is that they've been made generic (i.e. having type parameters).

Comment: I'm fool. I used "()" instead of "[]". It should be asInstanceOf[JComboBox[Array[java.lang.Object]]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type parameters are incorrect:

```
e.getSource.asInstanceOf[JComboBox(Array)].getValue)
```

should be

```
e.getSource.asInstanceOf[JComboBox[Array]].getValue)
```

Note the [Array]. This is how you specify type parameters in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this should give you instance of JComboBox

```
e.getSource.peer
```